# EXTJS Controller view autogenerated getter

Tags: controller, extjs, extjs4.1, getter, refs

I'm developping an Extjs app.
Here is one of my controllers

```
Ext.define('ACP.controller.CodeTabs', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

/*
views: [
    'CodeTabs'
],
*/

refs: [
    {
        ref: 'codetabs',
        selector: 'codetabs',
    }
],

init: function() {
    this.application.on({
        addtab: this.addTab,
        closetab: this.closeTab,
    });
},

addTab: function() {
    var tabs = this.getCodetabs();
    tabs.add(
        {
            title: 'New tab',
            iconCls: 'tabs',
            html: 'VICTORY',
        }
    ).show();
},

closeTab: function() {
    alert("closetab");
},
});
```

An here is the related view:

```
Ext.define('ACP.view.CodeTabs', {
extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
alias: 'widget.codetabs',
layout: 'fit',
items: [
    {
        title: 'Test',
        html: 'HELLO ASLAN'
    }
],
});
```

The problem is that the getter this.getCodetabs() is undefined. Isn't it supposed to be autogenerated by refs ? What am I doing wrong ?

Here is my application : http://atomcodepad.com/acp
You can try to click on the "addtab" button to see my problem happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're in the scope of the Application, not the Controller where the ref is defined.  Use the getController(name) method to get a reference to the controller, from there your getter is defined.

Comment: I corrected it like that:

    ...
     addTab: function() {
  var tabs = this.getController('CodeTabs').getCodetabs();
  tabs.add(
   {
    title: 'New tab',
    iconCls: 'tabs',
    html: 'VICTORY',
   }
  ).show();
 },
    ...
Is that the right way to do ?
In the Extjs doc I didn't see a single reference to the controller before calling the getter.

Whatever, now it works, thank you very much !